# X11 open on VNC server desktop opens windows on my VNC viewer instead of VNC server

Tags: x11, vnc

I'm having an interesting issue and my searches (plus the suggested articles here) aren't helping because I'm probably using the wrong terms.

I have three workstations:

1. Lin - a Linux instance running XServer.
2. Mac - a MacBook Pro with remote management enabled and XQuartz installed.
3. Win - Windows workstation running VNC Client.

Using VNC Client on Win, I am able to connect to and control the Mac desktop. This works as expected except that copy-paste doesn't work between them but that is a topic for another post.

Mac also has a connection to Lin, which is running X server.

When I am connected via VNC from Win to Mac, I open a Mac terminal, run "ssh -X user@Lin's address and connect successfully to Lin from Mac.

When I run "xterm" in that Mac terminal which is ssh -X to Lin, the xterm window opens on Mac as I expect.

However, when I run "chromium-browser", "firefox", etc in that same Mac terminal, the X window opens on Win, not Mac. Same behavior if I run an xwindows app in the xterm window on mac - it opens on Win, not Mac.

How is this possible and what can I do to control it? There may be times I might want that but mostly I want the X applications to run on Mac, not Win.

I get confused between which is the "server" and which is the "client" here, especially with three machines involved.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - it turned out I had an X server running on Win via MobaXTerm and the DISPLAY variable was not correctly set on Mac, so X was just passing the connection through.

I don't understand how that happened automatically via VNC (I didn't have any other connections between Win and Mac), but when I stopped the X server on Win and restarted the XQuartz app on Mac, windows began to open where I expected.